# Probability of a thrown coin avoiding grid lines

Tags: probability

> A 1-inch-diameter coin is thrown on a table covered with a grid of lines 
>       two inches apart.
>       What is the probability the coin lands in a square without touching any of
>       the lines of the grid?

Now how to go about this?Like I was thinking what relation can come out with the size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the location of the centre of the coin is uniformly distributed in a (random) square of the grid.

There's a central area in each square which has the property that if the centre of the coin falls into it, then the coin does not touch any of the lines. How large is that central area?

Divide this area by the area of the full square, and that's your probability.

Comment: Note that I'm neglecting any weird effects that may arise at the boundary of the table.

Comment: Oh wait..the total area is not given!

Comment: @joeyrohan the grid size is given, so the square is $2"$ side. The central zone is a smaller square of side _______.